# How to match immediately after for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, for-comprehension

I wanted to apply pattern matching immediately after `yield` in for-comprehension yielding `Option[Int]` as follows:

```
object Main extends App {
  val i: Int = for (
    int1 <- i1();
    int2 <- i2()
  ) yield (int2) match {
    case Some(i) => i
    case None => 0
  } 

  def i1(): Option[Int] = None

  def i2(): Option[Int] = None
}
```

[***DEMO***](https://ideone.com/FBWueY)

Unfortuantely it does not compile. Is there a way to avoid "temporary" `Option[Int]` result declaration?

Comment: You do nothing with `int1`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This is a simplified version of my actual case which is too large to be posted here.

Comment: The simplified version should still make sense? :)

Comment: Syntax around `for` and `match` get a lot of questions. For some reason, it's not quite intuitive or pretty enough.

Answer (score 4):

How about just adding brackets?

```
val i: Int = (for {
   int1 <- i1()
   int2 <- i2()
} yield (int2)) match {
   case Some(i) => i
   case None => 0
}
```

Edit: Added curly brackets

Comment: Obliviously in this example I'd just use `getOrElse(0)` but I assume this was just a basic example.

Comment: Please modify the for to remove the semi. Now I have to go flush my eyeballs.

Comment: Edited as that's my preferred way of writing it as well.